# scipy.ndimage.fourier_filter seems to work only for vector with index 0,0,: in array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, fft, moving-average

I'm trying to implement a moving average on the 3rd axis of a 3D array. As the moving window might be quite large, I wanted to do it in the Fourier domain to have decent speed. But it seems it works only for the vector in `arr[0,0,:]`.

Here is a minimal example with a test case. The first assertion passes, the second does not.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage as sni

def moving_average_in_ft(arr, size, axis=-1):
    """Perform moving average of given size along given axis of arr
    Performed in Fourier domain.
    Returns a complex result.
    """
    arr_ft = np.fft.fft(arr)
    nd_size = [1,] * arr.ndim # all other axes do not average
    nd_size[axis] = size
    return np.fft.ifft(sni.fourier_uniform(arr_ft, nd_size))


def test_moving_average_in_ft_and_time():
    a = np.random.rand(2, 2, 20)
    size = 9
    a_filt_ft = moving_average_in_ft(a, size).real
    a_filt_time = sni.uniform_filter(a, (1, 1, size), mode='wrap')
    # for the first ensemble it works
    ensamble_1 = (0, 0, slice(None))
    np.testing.assert_allclose(a_filt_ft[ensamble_1], a_filt_time[ensamble_1], atol=0.01)
    # but all the other ensembles don't
    np.testing.assert_allclose(a_filt_ft, a_filt_time, atol=0.1)
```

Comment: Could the difference between the methods come from the fact that the Fourier method wraps around? What happens if you pass an array that has a window (meaning has very low values towards the edges) ?

Comment: That's why I used `mode='wrap'` in `uniform_filter1d`. It works well enough for `a[0,0,:]` and that vector is not windowed.